# Laravel 5 scheduling on Win 10

Tags: laravel-5, scheduling, windows-task-scheduler

can you help me please to comprehend how to run Laravel 5.2 scheduling on Win 10? 
I have created Windows task according this http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html

```
SCHTASKS /Create /SC minute /TN Test2 /TR C:\Apache24\htdocs\example-laravel\win_cron.bat
```

It has been successfully created.
Also I have created .bat file according this link [Laravel 5.1 Task Scheduling on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950083/laravel-5-1-task-scheduling-on-windows)

```
cd c:\Apapche24\htdocs\example-laravel
php artisan schedule:run 1>> NUL 2>&1
```

In App\Console\Kernel class I have:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call( function()
    {
        Log::info( 'Some test message from   App\Console\Kernel:schedule.' );
    })->everyMinute();

}
```

It seems task is triggering every minute, but there is nothing in log. Also it returns 0x1 to the Task Scheduler window as last run result. 
If I run schedule:run via console it works as I expect. 
Any idea how to force it to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I found out here [Run a batch file with Windows task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437701/run-a-batch-file-with-windows-task-scheduler) it is necessary to set up "Start in" option in Windows Task scheduler in action tab of the task. So it is not necessary to create task  via command line.